# Aplicar efeito em scrool de UL

Tags: jquery, css, css3

É possível aplicar um efeito (`slideDown()` / `slideUp()`) em uma **barra de scroll** de uma **`<ul>`**?

Tipo assim: tenho uma `<ul>` que abre com efeito `slideDown()`. Essa `<ul>` tem uma `barra de scrool`. Gostaria que essa barra recebesse também o efeito para abrir junto com a `<ul>` acompanhando o efeito.

Como?

Comment: Pode tentar explicar melhor?

Comment: Alterada pergunta para melhor compreensão.